# Keeps Getting 1011 Errors Trying to Connect to Enfusion Systematic API

Tags: api

I am using Python 3.8 to connect to Enfusion Systematic API to get my OEMS blotter streamed, however, I am constantly getting 1011 errors.

I use a Mac and the command I run in my terminal is:

(base) Macs-MacBook-Pro-2:API Python Sample Mac$ python example.py -u username -p password; I got the sample scripts from Enfusion. Running the script, I got error below:
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: received 1011 (unexpected error); then sent 1011 (unexpected error)

Answer (score 0):

After checking my input a few times, I realized my password is incorrect.
I corrected my password and now I am successfully logged in.